# Prevent iframe onscroll event while scrolling main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mousewheel, onscroll

My main window has iframe which is set to no scrolling and I add onwheel event on main window page

```
window.onwheel= function() {
   //my code here
}
```

when my mouse pointer is over the iframe then main window onwheel event not worked.

iframe does not required scrolling but its height dynamic, it changed according to page height. its my requirement to use iframe in the page.

I want when my pointer is over the iframe then main window onwheel event should be work.

How can I solved this problem using js or css ? Please help!!!

Comment: "_I want when my pointer is over the iframe still this main window onscroll event should be work_" In that case, how you're supposed to scroll the iframe?

Comment: i dont want scroll in iframe, no scroll use in iframe

Comment: There's something wrong in this scenario, if there's no use for scroll in the iframe, then it won't scroll ...

Comment: Its my requirement, I have to use it and its height changing dynamically so there is no scroll use in the iframe

Comment: ?? But then the main page scrolls normally, no matter where the mouse pointer would be?? No need for separate JS scroll handler.

Comment: I need some additional task thats need to be perform on window scroll like more data load when scroll reached bottom. can you tell me what is the issue ?

Comment: Cover the iframe with a transparent `<div>`

Comment: @charlietfl its already inside the div

Comment: Put another div that is positioned over top of the iframe... when mouse enters an iframe, events occur inside the iframe window, not main page window

Comment: like a transparent modal screen over the iframe. yeah that good option but can you tell me why this problem occur @charlietfl

Comment: Just did....there are 2 different windows ...main page and iframe. Events in iframe window don't bubble to main page window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149219/discussion-between-kushal-jain-and-charlietfl).